# Android Studio Fragment with custom fragment class object

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

I just created a fragment in my app which consists of some controls. In principle, I want these controls to send their current data over a tcp client, which has a method `TcpClient::sendMessage` which relates to the tcp socket. The fragment itself consits of an interface, which is used to create a callback to the `MainActivity`, which holds the fragment.
This is how i attatch the fragment to my `MainActivity`:

```
FragmentControls fragmentControls = new FragmentControls((command, message) -> tcp_client.sendMessage(command, message));
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
   .setReorderingAllowed(true)
   .add(R.id.fragment_pi_connected, FragmentControls.class, null)
   .commit();
```

How can i manage to create the Fragment with the initialized object `fragmentControls` in the first line, to implement the interface function?

For completeness, my Fragment class:

```
public class FragmentControls extends Fragment {
    public CommandSendInterface commandSendInterface;

    public FragmentControls(CommandSendInterface sendCommandInterface) {
        super(R.layout.maunal_pi_controls);
        commandSendInterface = sendCommandInterface;
    }

   // Some stuff that handles the View Objects in the Fragment and treats their events...

    public interface CommandSendInterface{
        void onCommandSend(ServerCommands command, int message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should have just passed the object as argument instead of the .class value, now it works perfectly.